# Adjektiv für "In Kategorien unterteilt"

Tags: single-word-request, adjective

Existiert ein Adjektiv, welches eine in Kategorien unterteilte Liste beschreibt?

Ich gehe davon aus, dass eine *kategorisierte Liste* an dieser Stelle nicht stimmt, sondern beifügt, dass die Liste selbst einer Kategorie zugeordnet ist.

Comment: _kategorial_ oder das Partizip _kategorisierend_

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Vielen Dank. Wenn du möchtest kannst du den Kommentar gerne als Antwort posten und ich wäre glücklich ihn zu akzeptieren.

Comment: Ich bin nicht der Ansicht, dass *kategorisierte Liste* hier falsch ist - Dann wären die gängigen Begriffe *geordnete Liste* und *sortierte Liste* mit der gleichen Argumentation auch falsch, da dort natürlich auch die Listeneinträge und nicht etwa die Liste selbst geordnet und sortiert werden. Ich befürchte, du bist hier etwas zu spitzfindig.

Comment: @tofro Sehr guter Punkt. Gute Beispiele. Ich bin überzeugt :)

Comment: @tofro Siehe dir gerne trotzdem die Antwort von Björn Friedrich an.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich würde *kategorial* verwenden. Das Partizip *kategorisierend* würde auch funktionieren.

**Einwand zu *kategorisiert*:**
Normalerweise kategorisiert man einzelne Dinge, d. h. man ordnet einzelne Dinge einer Kategorie zu. Ein solches Ding kann dann die Eigenschaft besitzen, kategorisiert, d. h. einer Kategorie zugeordnet, zu sein. Die Liste aller dieser kategorisierten Dinge selbst hat diese Eigenschaft nicht - zumindest wenn man von dem Sonderfall, mehrere Listen kategorisieren zu wollen, absieht.

Beim *Sortieren* ist das anders, denn hier ist nicht ein einzelnes herausgegriffenes Ding sortiert, sondern tatsächlich die Gesamtheit der Dinge, also die Liste selbst.

Übrigens: Passend zum Thema nennt man die Zuordnung von Eigenschaften zu Dingen, die diese Eigenschaft gar nicht haben können einen *Kategorienfehler*. Bei der Verwendung des Ausdrucks *kategorisierte Liste* begehen wir also einen *Kategorienfehler* - sofern wir den zuvor erwähnten Sonderfall ausschließen.